# Issue with PyAutoGUI module working with chrome

Tags: python, pyautogui

I m trying to run a python script that open chrome go to google and type my search automatically but it only open chrome but it does not type anything. this would work if I type in notepad for example but not in the browser. What m I missing in here ?

```
import webbrowser
from datetime import time

import pyautogui

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')  # Go to example.com
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(453,373);

time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite('search images');
```

Answer (score 0):

The search bar should already be in focus so there is no need to click in the page. And `time.sleep()` is from the `time` module. This works for me.

```
import webbrowser, time, pyautogui

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')  # Go to example.com
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite('search images')
```